# What is the correct way to detect a file path out of 2 or more possible path's within an ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I'm writing an Ansible playbook which will install and configure an agent of some monitoring system my company uses. One of the steps required for the successful configuration of the agent is to configure certain directives in `nagios.cfg` file.

The nagios.cfg can reside on two different paths based on the way it was installed (package manager / from source).

The two relevant paths are:

```
/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg
```

What I want Ansible to do is to find the correct path and then insert it into a variable which I'll be able to use in the following configuration steps.

I've started with this:

```
- stat: path=/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
  register: nag_conf_usrlocal
  when: nag_conf_usrlocal.stat.exists
```

I thought about stating the file in the first location, understand if it exists there and if so then insert it to a variable and if it's not there then the next path should be stat'ed and if the file exists there then variable should include the correct path where the file exists.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is not wrong, it just needs some fixing:

```
- stat: path=/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
  register: nag_conf_usrlocal

- stat: path=/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg
  register: nag_conf_etc
  when: nag_conf_usrlocal.stat.exists

- set_fact: 
     nagios_path: "/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg"
  when: nag_conf_usrlocal.stat.exists

- set_fact: 
     nagios_path: "/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg"
  when: nag_conf_etc.stat.exists
```

This is probably not the best solution, but it's to give you an overwiew of how this could be achieved.